# How to create an instance geo:point with keyValues? (Simple Location Format)

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

If I created an entity with this JSON with `options=keyValues`:

```
{
       "id": "waterqualityobserved:Sevilla:D3",
       "type": "WaterQualityObserved",
       "location": "41.3763726, 2.186447514"
}
```

Then request: `localhost:1026/v2/entities/waterqualityobserved:Sevilla:D3`

```
{
    "id": "waterqualityobserved:Sevilla:D3",
    "type": "WaterQualityObserved",
    "location": {
        "type": "Text",
        "value": "41.3763726, 2.186447514",
        "metadata": {}
    }
}
```

Orion is able to execute geographical queries?
How else to define the location property?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify attribute types if you use keyValues mode. Thus, if you want to specify a `geo:point` type for an attribute meaning a GPS location, you have to use the default representation mode.

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to do it. If you are going to create an entity with a geospatial property such as location you would need to use the normalized format i.e. including the "value" and "metadata" members for each attribute.